# Generate Random(a, b) making calls to Random(0, 1)

Tags: algorithm, random

There is known `Random(0,1)` function, it is a uniformed random function, which means, it will give 0 or 1, with probability 50%. Implement `Random(a, b)` that only makes calls to `Random(0,1)`

What I though so far is,  put the range a-b in a 0 based array, then I have index 0, 1, 2...b-a.

then call the `RANDOM(0,1)` b-a times, sum the results as generated idx. and return the element.

However since there is no answer in the book, I don't know if this way is correct or the best. How to prove that the probability of returning each element is exactly same and is `1/(b-a+1)` ?

And what is the right/better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get random numbers with the wrong generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694933/how-to-get-random-numbers-with-the-wrong-generator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your RANDOM(0, 1) returns either 0 or 1, each with probability 0.5 then you can generate bits until you have enough to represent the number (b-a+1) in binary. This gives you a random number in a slightly too large range: you can test and repeat if it fails. Something like this (in Python).

```
def rand_pow2(bit_count):
    """Return a random number with the given number of bits."""
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(bit_count):
        result = 2 * result + RANDOM(0, 1)
    return result

def random_range(a, b):
    """Return a random integer in the closed interval [a, b]."""
    bit_count = math.ceil(math.log2(b - a + 1))
    while True:
        r = rand_pow2(bit_count)
        if a + r <= b:
            return a + r
```

Comment: This solution produces a uniform distribution by producing a uniform distribution over 0..(2^N-1) then discarding the result if it's out of the required range to construct a uniform distribution over a non-power of 2. Your solution constructs a binomial distribution.

Comment: i got it, your way is correct. but the result line would be `result += RANDOM(0,1) * 2 ** i` right?

Comment: Yes, you can construct it either way, or even result += RANDOM(0, 1) << i.

Answer (score 2):

When you sum random numbers, the result is not longer evenly distributed - it looks like a Gaussian function.  Look up "law of large numbers" or read any probability book / article.  Just like flipping coins 100 times is highly highly unlikely to give 100 heads.  It's likely to give close to 50 heads and 50 tails.

Comment: thanks for the information, I will search some related articles to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your inclination to put the range from `0` to `a-b` first is correct. However, you cannot do it as you stated. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694933/how-to-get-random-numbers-with-the-wrong-generator) asks exactly how to do that, and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7694958/544050) utilizes unique factorization. Write `m=a-b` in base `2`, keeping track of the largest needed exponent, say `e`. Then, find the biggest multiple of `m` that is smaller than `2^e`, call it `k`. Finally, generate `e` numbers with `RANDOM(0,1)`, take them as the base `2` expansion of some number `x`, if `x < k*m`, return `x`, otherwise try again. The program looks something like this (simple case when m<2^2):

```
int RANDOM(0,m) {

    // find largest power of n needed to write m in base 2
    int e=0;
    while (m > 2^e) {
        ++e;
    }

    // find largest multiple of m less than 2^e
    int k=1;
    while (k*m < 2^2) {
        ++k
    }
    --k; // we went one too far

    while (1) {
        // generate a random number in base 2
        int x = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<e; ++i) {
            x = x*2 + RANDOM(0,1); 
        }
        // if x isn't too large, return it x modulo m
        if (x < m*k) 
            return (x % m);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply add `a` to the result to get uniformly distributed numbers between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer could help us in generating a random number in range [a,b] using random(0,1). The idea is

1. if a is equal to b, then random number is a
2. Find mid of the range [a,b]
3. Generate random(0,1)
4. If above is 0, return a random number in range [a,mid] using recursion
5. else return a random number in range [mid+1, b] using recursion

The working 'C' code is as follows.

```
int random(int a, int b)
{ 
    if(a == b)
        return a;

    int c = RANDOM(0,1); // Returns 0 or 1 with probability 0.5
    int mid = a + (b-a)/2;

    if(c == 0)
       return random(a, mid);
    else
       return random(mid + 1, b);
}
```

Comment: This will only result in a uniform distribution if all subranges are equal in size, which only happens if the range is a power of 2. It's mathematically equivalent to generating the bits, and you only get uniformity if you reject the bit-sets that are outside the range for ranges that aren't powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a RNG that returns `{0, 1}` with equal probability, you can easily create a RNG that returns numbers `{0, 2^n}` with equal probability.

To do this you just use your original RNG `n` times and get a binary number like `0010110111`. Each of the numbers are (from 0 to 2^n) are equally likely.

Now it is easy to get a RNG from `a` to `b`, where `b - a = 2^n`. You just create a previous RNG and add `a` to it.

Now the last question is what should you do if `b-a` is not `2^n`?

---

Good thing that you have to do almost nothing. Relying on [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) technique. It tells you that if you have a big set and have a RNG over that set and need to select an element from a subset of this set, you can just keep selecting an element from a bigger set and discarding them till they exist in your subset.

So all you do, is find `b-a` and find the first n such that `b-a <= 2^n`. Then using rejection sampling till you picked an element smaller `b-a`. Than you just add `a`.